# How can I change the background color of a cell in a jqgrid custom formatter?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, formatter

I can change the text color by doing this in jqgrid custom formatter:

```
function YNFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
    var color = (cellvalue == "Y") ? "green" : "red";
    var cellHtml = "<span style='color:" + color + "' originalValue='" +
                                cellvalue + "'>" + cellvalue + "</span>";

    return cellHtml;
 }
```

but I want to now change the **background color of the whole cell** (instead of the text color).

Is this possible?

Comment: @harshhh - i added another comment

Comment: You should just use `'background-color'` instead of `'color'` and set additional style `'background-image':'none'` to remove the background image inherited from the jQuery UI class 'ui-widget-content'. If you want additionally use standard color for hovering or/and selected rows you can use technique which I described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956949/make-selected-color-highest-level-in-jqgrid/4960622#4960622

Comment: @Oleg - background-color is only for the span (not the whole TD cell)

Comment: @ooo: In your question you wrote, that you want/have to use custom formatter. The text returned by the custom formatter will be placed in the `<td>` cell. So in the way you have no chance to change the `<td>` itself. Maximum what you can do is to place any element like `<span>` which could have the whole size of the `<td>` (depend on the used CSS). In the case the background of `<span>` will be seen for the user exactly like the cells background. Using custom formatter you can not do more.

Comment: @ooo: To make all clear I do wrote my answer.

Comment: @Oleg - thanks for the example (and your patience).. very helpful indeed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want use `<span>` element inside of the custom cell formatter you can return from the custom formatter

```
return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' +
       color + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
```

where the style of `span.cellWithoutBackground` you can define for example like following

```
span.cellWithoutBackground
{
    display:block;
    background-image:none;
    margin-right:-2px;
    margin-left:-2px;
    height:14px;
    padding:4px;
}
```

How it works you can see live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BackgroundColorFormatter.htm):
[image]

**UPDATED:** The answer is old. The best practice would be to use `cellattr` callback in `colModel` instead of the usage custom formatters. Changing of background color of the cell is in general just assigning `style` or `class` attribute to the cells of the column (`<td>` elements). The `cellattr` callback defined in the column of `colModel` allows exactly to do this. One can still use *predefined formatters* like `formatter: "checkbox"`, `formatter: "currency"`, `formatter: "date"` and so on, but still change the background color in the column. In the same way the `rowattr` callback, which can be defined as the jqGrid option (outside of specific column of `colModel`), allows to assign style/class of the whole row (`<tr>` elements).

More information about `cellattr` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935), for example. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) explains `rowattr`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
    ...
       colModel: [
          ...
          {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true, formatter:myFmatter},
          ...
       ],
        afterInsertRow: function(rowId, data)
        {
            $("#grid_id").setCell(rowId, 'price', '', {'background-color':'#' + data.colorHEX});
        }
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
$("#cell").setCell(Row , Column, Value, { background: '#888888'});
```

Actually you won't even need custom formatter, if you just intend to do it for setting colors.
You can even set color value from here like,

```
var color = (Value == "Y") ? "green" : "red";
$("#cell").setCell(Row , Column, Value, { background: '#888888', color: color});
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: @harshh - are you saying to put this line in my custom formatter code function?

Comment: @harshh - i actually want to do it as a custom formatter as i have some conditional logic based on other data properties. Also,where are you getting Row, Column and Value from ?

Comment: @ooo: You should don't use custom formatter. Instead of that you can  change the background color of some cells inside of `loadComplete` event. You can get ids of the loaded data with respect of `getDataIDs` method, then get the cell data in a loop with `getCell` examine there and change style of cell with `setCell` using empty string as a data parameter (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods for details). You can also use 'formatter:checkbox' additionally.

Comment: You can use any jqGrid features which you like. Usage of custom formatting is in general to produce a HTML code for a cell. To set background color it is enough only set a CSS class on the cell. I would define in you CSS two classes "redBackground" and "greenBackground" and set on the cell only one from the classes. As a formatter I'll use 'formatter:checkbox'. You can do what you prefer.

Comment: @Oleg - i am doing this in combination with other text formatting on the cell so i already am using a custom formatter. because of this i hoped there was one extra line that allowed me to add background color in this custom formatter function