# Colors in rows and Edit values but dont show Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, hidden

I want to know if its possible use different background colors for each (or some) row/s..

And I have another problem, i have defined checkbox that i want to set only when add, but i don't want see it when the grid is showing all the rows..Is this possible?

Here is my code..

```
$("#<%=Me.Id & "_" %>lstBaseHab").jqGrid({
    url: '/modulos/tarifa/basehabitacion.ashx',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Hab ID','Habitación','Importe', 'Fecha Inicio','Fecha Fin','Noches Estancia/Mínimas','Todos','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado','Domingo','tarId', 'estId'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'hab_id', index: 'hab_id', width: 100, align: 'center', editable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true},
        {name: 'hab_nombre', index: 'hab_nombre', width: 200, align: 'center', edittype: 'select', editable: true, sortable: false, editrules: { edithidden: false, required: true }
        , editoptions: { size: 1, dataUrl: '/modulos/tarifa/basehabitacion.ashx?oper=listahabs' }
        },
        { name: 'tpb_importe', index: 'tpb_importe', width: 160, align: 'center', editable: true, sortable: true },
        { name: 'fini', index: 'fini', width: 300, align: 'center', editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); }, 200); } }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: true },
        { name: 'ffin', index: 'ffin', width: 300, align: 'center', editable: true, editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }); }, 200); } }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: true },
        { name: 'Nochesestancia', index: 'Nochesestancia', width: 300, align: 'center', sortable: false, editable: true },
        { name: 'Lun', index: 'lun', width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "1:" }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Mar', index: 'mar', width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "2:" }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Mie', index: 'mie', width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "3:" }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Jue', index: 'jue', width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "4:" }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Vie', index: 'vie', width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "5:" }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Sab', index: 'sab', width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "6:" }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Dom', index: 'dom', width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center', editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "0:" }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false }
    ],
    ajaxSelectOptions: {
        data: {
            estId: function () { return __estId; }
        }
    },
    ajaxGridOptions: {cache: false},
    autoencode: false,
    toppager: false,
    loadonce:false,
    pager: '#preciobasepager',
    rowNum: 40,
    rowList: [20, 40, 80, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
    sortname: 'fini',
    sortorder: 'asc',
    autowidth: false,
    width: 850,
    height: -1,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    prmNames: {oper:"listarbaseshabitacion", addoper:"crearbasehabita", deloper:"borrabasehabita"},
    caption: 'Precios base para habitaciones'
    , editurl: '/modulos/tarifa/basehabitacion.ashx'
    , postData: {
        tarId: function ftar(){return __tarId;},
        estId: function fest(){return __estId;}
    }, afterSaveCell : function(rowid,name,val,iRow,iCol) { }
    , loadComplete: function() { }
    , onCellSelect: function(rowid, index, contents, event) {
        <%=Me.id %>_selectedRow=jQuery(this).getRowData(rowid);
    }
});

jQuery("#<%=Me.Id & "_" %>lstBaseHab").jqGrid('navGrid',
    '#preciobasepager',
    { alerttext: "Seleccione un registro.",
        add: true, addtitle: "Crear precio base", //addfunc: newPrecioBase, 
        del: true, deltitle: "Eliminar precio base", // delfunc: delPrecioBase,
        edit: false, edittitle: "Editar precio base",
        search: false, searchtitle: "Buscar",
        refresh: true,
        cloneToTop: true
    },
    { width: 350, resize: false, closeAfterEdit: true, recreateForm: true, viewPagerButtons: true, afterComplete: null },
    { width: 350, resize: false, closeAfterAdd: true, recreateForm: true, viewPagerButtons: true, afterComplete: null },
    { width: 350, resize: false, msg: "¿Desea eliminar la relación?", afterComplete: null }
);
```

If I put `hidden:true` (as can see it in the `colModel`) its hidden showing, but i cant define it when add..

Thanks.

Comment: You should better format code which you included in the question. You can remove unneeded spaces on the left size in any text editor which you use. Alternatively you can select the rows where you need remove unneeded spaces and click on "{ }" button. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) for example more how you can format the code in the editor of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

To set background color on individual rows, for example based on the content of come columns if the grid, you can use `rowattr` callback. It provide the most effective solution (if you use `gridview: true`) because it allows you modify attributes of rows *dynamically* at the moment of creating of the rows. So you will just inform jqGrid which additional attributes you want to have in rows.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) demonstrate the approach.

The second part of your question (about checkboxs) is not clear for me. The standard `formatter: "chechboxs"` will be used for displaying data in the grid and for editing. You can implement your requirements if you remove `formatter: "chechboxs"` but implement all additional behavior which you need inside of `dataInit` callback of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). One more possibility which you have is the usage of [custom editing control](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#custom).

**UPDATED**: I would recommend you additionally to use [column templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6047856/315935). You have multiple columns where you use checkboxes and multiple columns ('fini', 'ffin') where you use datepicker. So your code will be smaller, more readable and better manageable if you define somewhere in your code above definition of jqGrid variables which hold common properties for the columns:

```
var dateTemplate = { width: 300, align: 'center', editable: true
        editoptions: {
            dataInit: function(el) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(el).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
                }, 200);
            }
        }, editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: true },
    checkboxTemplate = {width: 50,  formatter: "checkbox", align: 'center',
        editable: true, hidden: true, edittype: "checkbox",
        editrules: { edithidden: false }, sortable: false};
```

then you will be able to rewrite definition of the corresponding columns of jqGrid inside of `colModel` to the following:

```
{ name: 'fini', template: dateTemplate },
{ name: 'ffin', template: dateTemplate },
...
{ name: 'Lun', index: 'lun', editoptions: {value: "1:"}, template: checkboxTemplate },
{ name: 'Mar', index: 'mar', editoptions: {value: "2:"}, template: checkboxTemplate },
{ name: 'Mie', index: 'mie', editoptions: {value: "3:"}, template: checkboxTemplate },
{ name: 'Jue', index: 'jue', editoptions: {value: "4:"}, template: checkboxTemplate },
{ name: 'Vie', index: 'vie', editoptions: {value: "5:"}, template: checkboxTemplate },
{ name: 'Sab', index: 'sab', editoptions: {value: "6:"}, template: checkboxTemplate },
{ name: 'Dom', index: 'dom', editoptions: {value: "0:"}, template: checkboxTemplate }
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, if i use rowattr but i dont know what data arrives, how can i do it? For example, i can recieve 2 or 3 differents "hab_nombre" can i do `rowattr: function (rd) {
    if (rd.GroupHeader === "1") { // verify that the testing is correct in your case
        return {"class": "myAltRowClass"};
    }` but with some for each different .. ?

Comment: In the second part, sorry for my explanation, i have all the colmodel that you can see, but "Lun, Mar, Mie, Jue, Vie, Sab, Dom" i only want to set when add a row, but when the grid shows the data, i dont want see this columns..Do you understand me?

Comment: @bombai: If you use `datatype: "xml"` the code could be a little more complex. You could use the code like `$('cell:eq(1)', rd)` to get required data. See [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8022860/315935) for details. It describes `cellattr` instead of `rowattr`, but the problem are the same in both cases. I included in the "UPDATED" part of my answer additional information about column templates which I would recommend you to use.

Comment: @bombai: about `"Lun, Mar, Mie, Jue, Vie, Sab, Dom"` I still don't understand what you want to have. Do you want probably have *one* input field with 7 chechboxes during editing of grid?

Comment: @bombai: Probably you need to use `edithidden: true`. In the case the hidden fields will be created automatically in the Add/Edit form. So you need just show the fields. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3405961/315935). You need just simplify the code and use always `beforeShowForm: function() { $('#tr_Lun,#tr_Mar,#tr_Mie,#tr_Jue,#tr_Vie,#tr_Sab,#tr_Dom').show(); }`

Comment: I have a problem with the rowattr code above, because i dont know which values can have it the cell, i need to define a different colour for each different value..Do you know how can i do this?

Comment: @bombai: I wrote you before that you posted not enough information. You should include at least one row of data which will be returned from `'/modulos/tarifa/basehabitacion.ashx'`. Moreover you should specify more clear at least some simple criteria how you want choose the color of row.

Comment: Sorry about Oleg. Here you can view a screenshot http://i.imgbox.com/acn0jIxH.jpg, as you can see, i want all the Habitación "Doble", for example, in orange, the Individual in green, but i dont know how many differents kinds can i recieve..I will not recieve more than 5 differents kinds, but the number and type is dinamic.. Thanks.