# How to set CSS Class to JQGrid?

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, evopdf

I am developing a website with a JQGrid on it. I am also turning the table to PDF. I want to show table header on every page so that PDF converter I have need to set CSS a property THEAD tag of the table to "display:table-header-group".

So how do I set that CSS property in JQGrid?

Thanks.

Comment: If you examine the structure of the grid created by jqGrid you will see that in consist of *multiple* dives which contains *multiple* tables. Which `<thead>` of which table you want change? Moreover I have not enough experience with `display:table-header-group` CSS style, but it looks more helpful in the case that you use some other elements as `<table>`. For example you can use `<p>` or `<div>` elements and display structure close to `<table>`. So I don't understand what is your goal of usage `display:table-header-group`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rows>
<page>1</page><total>1</total><records>2</records>
    <row id='13'>
        <cell>1.00</cell>
        <cell class='ui-state-error'>15.00</cell>
        <cell>9.00</cell>
    </row>
    <row id='12'>
        <cell>1.00</cell>
        <cell>2.00</cell>
        <cell class='ui-state-highlight'>1.15</cell>
    </row>
</rows>


 cellattr: function () {
    var c = $('cell:eq(1)', arguments[2]).attr('class');
    return c ? " class='" + c + "'": "";
}
```

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022038/jqgrid-how-to-set-cell-specific-css-class-at-generation-time)