# jqGrid custom format fails on addClass

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, addclass

I populate a new grid from json
with custom formatter
the formatter is defined :

```
testFormatter(value,el,opts)
{
     if (value==0)
     {
          $(el).addClass("Fail");
     }
     …
}
```

I am expecting the cells to use the css class
but If I check the cells they don't add that class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made the typical error of the usage of the [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). It is important to understand that the jqGrid has the best performance if the grid contain will be created as **the string**. In the case the `gridview:true` gives you the performance. Any [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) should work in the `gridview:true` mode, so the custom formater **has no parameter** which are DOM element and so you can not use operations like `$(el).addClass("Fail");`

In some old answers (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244909/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-cell-in-a-jqgrid-custom-formatter/4981389#4981389) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942761/how-to-change-the-color-of-jqgrid-cell/4943722#4943722)) you can find how the problem can be solved, but I would you suggest to use new feature of jqGrid 4.0.0: `cellattr` option. For undefrstanding: the purpose of the custom formatter is not add some HTML attributes like class for example. It should be used for example to convert some universal date format like yyyy-mm-dd to localized form like dd.mm.yyyy (German style). If you don't want to change format of the column, but want only add some **attributes** like `title` (used for tooltips), `class` (like in your case), `style` and so on the new `cellattr` option is what you need.

In you case you can define

```
cellattr: function(rowId, cellValue, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
    if (cellValue==0) {
        return ' class="Fail"';
    }
}
```

See a small demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithAddClass.htm):

[image]

In the demo I added calsses `ui-state-error` and `ui-state-error-text` to all cells of `'Client'` column where in the `'Closed'` the checkbox is set.

Comment: thanks for the answer, It seems I can't find documentation of `cellattr` in jqgrid site, just that they added it.

Comment: @shevski: there are many intresting new options  which are not yet described in the documenation. The column templates for example are introduced in jqGrid 3.8.2, but still not described in the documentation (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044047/stopping-columns-resizable-in-jqgrid/6047856#6047856)). If you search in the trirand forum for `cellattr` you will find some information.