# Remove blank column in jqGrid - Pivot

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid, jqpivot

I have created a jqGrid - Pivot table JSFiddle example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b47ocLd7/6/).

In this It should not print the line if `Component Type` value is blank, I Used this empty column, to show all periods(months) in the year, which is mandatory.

Need help in removing that blank line. and also is it possible to remove the last sum column `2015` from grid, if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You includes dummy data with `ComponentType:""` group which you don't want to display. So the best solution which I see would be to include the data in the input pivot data only, but **don't use the dummy data in the grid data**. jqPivot uses `datatype: "jsonstring"` to prevent additional sorting of previously sorted data. The input data will be placed as the value of `datastr` option. So one can use the following `onInitGrid` to remove the dummy data *before* the data will be processed by jqGrid:

```js
onInitGrid: function () {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        userdata = p.datastr.userdata;

    p.datastr = $.grep(p.datastr, function (item) {
        return item.ComponentType !== "";
    });
    p.datastr.userdata = userdata;
}
```

see the modified demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/b47ocLd7/11/.

Comment: @ManiDeep: Sorry, but how the blank line can come again if no data exist in the grid? Do you do something like http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/b47ocLd7/13/? I don't see any problems.

Comment: @ManiDeep: You placed `loadComplete` in your last demo on absolutely wrong place. The 3-d parameter of `jqPivot` specify jqGrid options. You included `{ loadComplete: function() {...} }` and the options where `onInitGrid` are used will be now in **the 4-d parameter** of `jqPivot` and will be interpreted as Ajax options. So `onInitGrid` which I suggested will be not used. You should use something like http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/b47ocLd7/16/.

Comment: oh.. sorry i didnt knew that.. yea it is wokring, and from your example
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14694528/2750968 here , even font-weight:bold of header is not working :(

Comment: and if u can share a link of the using parameters of jquery.. itll be usefull :)
thanks

Comment: omg I just noticed, the summary (sum values at the bottom of grid are not loading) from the main answer u sent..

Comment: @ManiDeep: Sorry, but I don't understand the last problem. You use **grouping of data**. [The old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14694528/2750968) shows how to set **bold** style in **TreeGrid**. Tree grid elements have `parent` property which is the id of parent row or `"null"` for the root nodes. Thus the answer uses `rd.parent === "null"` to set the class on the nodes.

Comment: is it possible to add sorting option to `Component Type` aswell? as it is for all the measures and component name ?

Comment: @ManiDeep: You should change `groupingView.groupOrder` dynamically if the user click on sorting of column from `groupingView.groupField` array. The problem exist only if `groupingView.groupColumnShow` contains `true` element. Typically one uses `groupingView.groupColumnShow: [false]` and there are no column for the grouping column at all.

Comment: Here, if the blank line without component type has a value, then that line's value is also being added in the overall sum at footer of grid.. (but we have removed it from display), how to ignore its value also from being added? as in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manideep/bkqce0s0/2/  (jan-15 has no records, we reomved from disply, but still has value in summary footer)

Comment: @ManiDeep: I don't understand what you mean. You wrote that you added dummy rows only to have more columns. Why the values could exist? The Pivot generates columns of jqGrid and calculates in the same time the summary results. If you want, you can change the values from the footer row inside of `onInitGrid`. The `userdata` is the object with the footer values. So you can reduce the value on the values from removed rows (rows where `item.ComponentType !== ""`).

Comment: can you please join group: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75790/discussion-between-mani-deep-and-oleg

Comment: @ManiDeep: Sorry, but I spent already too many time for your questions. I have other things to do.

Comment: ohk, actually it was not related to this question. @Oleg thanks for your time