# how to change the color of one of the cell of jqgrid?

Tags: css, jqgrid

I have create a jqgird,it contains two column,one is time1 and the other is time2.When the time of column time1 is earlier than time of column time2,the color of the cell of the time1 will change to red,how can i make it?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `cellattr` or `rowattr`. If you want to change the color (or background color) of the *cell* `time1` based on the value of `time2` you can use `cellattr` property defined in the column `time1`. Look in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180842/315935) or [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048865/315935) for more details. You can use typically `rawObject.time2` to access to the value of `time2` column. The exact format of `rawObject` depends on `datatype` which you use ("json", "xml" or "local"), depend on the usage of `loadonce` option and from the exact format of the input data (described in `jsonReader` or `xmlReader`).

If you decide to change the color of the whole row instead of the cell in the column `time1` you should use `rowattr` option of grid instead of `cellattr` in `colModel`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935) for more details. Be careful, `cellattr` should returns string, but `rowattr` returns object. Moreover you should use property enclose in quote `"class"` (like in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935)) because some browsers interpret `class` property as reserved name.