# formatting cell background color based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

i am trying to change cell background color based on condition on particular column, it is not working.please help to me to resolve. this is what i have tried.
my php page for your reference. thanks. i found a solution but it doesnt work on my php page. this that solution http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BackgroundColorFormatter.htm

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$val = mysqli_query($con,"select storenm,FA_SOH,FA_CY_QTY,FA_CT_QTY from pr_report");

   $arr=array();
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($val)){
       $arr[] = "["."'".$row['storenm']."'".","."'".$row['FA_SOH']."'".","."'".$row['FA_CY_QTY']."'"."]";
   }
   $assign = implode(',',$arr);

   ?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>




<meta charset="utf-8">


<!--jQuery dependencies-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid files-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="pqgrid.min.css" />
    <script src="pqgrid.min.js"></script>
<!--PQ Grid Office theme-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/office/pqgrid.css" />
<style type="text/css">
        span.cellWithoutBackground
        {
            display:block;
            background-image:none;
            margin-right:-2px;
            margin-left:-2px;
            height:14px;
            padding:4px;
        }
    </style>
<script>
    $(function () {
    var data = [<?PHP echo $assign;?>];
          var obj = { 
          swipeModel: { on : true },
          //scrollModel: { autoFit: true },
            title: "Grid From JSON",
            collapsible: { on: true, collapsed: false },
virtualX: false,
virtualY: false,
        freezeRows: 0,

            freezeCols: 1,
            editable: false,  
            resizable: false,
        width: 400, 
        height: 400, 
        title: "ParamQuery Grid Example"
        };

        obj.colModel = [{ 
        title: "Storenm", width: 100, dataType: "string" },
        { title: "FSOH", width: 200, dataType: "float",align: "center" },
        { title: "FCY", width: 150, dataType: "float",align: "center",
                        formatter: function (cellvalue) {
                            var color;
                            var val = Number(cellvalue);
                            if (val>25) {
                                color = 'red';
                            } else if (val>15) {
                                color = 'yellow';
                            } else {
                                color = 'green';
                            }

                            return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' + color + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
                        }
                    }, 
        { title: "Profits ($ millions)", width: 150, dataType: "float", align: "right"}];

        obj.dataModel = {data: data};
        $("#grid_array").pqGrid(obj);

    });

</script>    
</head>
<body>
<div id="grid_array" style="margin:100px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You try to use **very old** example, which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981389/315935). Later I suggested to include another features: `cellattr` and `rowattr`, which I recommend to use instead of usage custom formatters just to set **attributes** and not the content of the cell. Look at [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180718/adding-a-css-class-to-a-column/12180842#12180842) for an example of usage `cellattr`. You can use, for example, the `formatter: "number"` to format *the content* of the column, and to use `cellattr` to set `class` *attribute* on the cells to change the background color of the cells.

You posted some code, where you don't use jqGrid at all. I suppose, that you wrote some wrapper `pqGrid`, which use `colModel` for jqGrid.

In any way, it's important to take in consideration some CSS rules to change the background color. You use currently `background-color` property to change the color. The default jQuery UI CSS apply `background-image` on the cells too. To be able to change the background color to red, for example, you can use either both `background-color` and `background-image`

```css
background-color: red;
background-image: none;
```

or to use

```css
background: red;
```

which reset `background-image` together with the `background-color`.

The next problem. If you apply the CSS properties by usage a CSS rule, then the usage of

```css
span.cellWithoutBackground {
    background-image:none;
}
```

or

```css
.backgroundRed {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: none;
}
```

will not work because there are exist jQuery UI rules with *two* selectors, which set background too. To force that your CSS rule will be applied you should use more complex CSS selector. For example

```css
.ui-jqgrid .jqgrow .backgroundRed {
   background-color: red;
   background-image: none;
}
```

(the classes `jqgrow` and `ui-jqgrid` are applied on the outer elements).

Comment: thank you sir, i have tried the below, but it is not working. i am new to CSS. this is what i have tried `.pq-grid-cell.cellWithoutBackground{
    
            display:block;
   background-color: red;
            background-image:none;
            margin-right:-2px;
            margin-left:-2px;
            height:14px;
            padding:4px;
        }`

Comment: @davidb: You are welcome! What exactly you tried? Where is your current code or the demo?

Comment: @davidb: The rule `.pq-grid-cell.cellWithoutBackground` (without spaces) will be applied on the elemen which have **both** classes `pq-grid-cell` and `.cellWithoutBackground`. I suggested you to use the rule `.ui-jqgrid .jqgrow .cellWithoutBackground`, which means the element with `cellWithoutBackground` class only, but which parent (the row `<tr>`) has the class `jqgrow`, which parent (outer `<div>` used by jqGrid) has the class `.ui-jqgrid`.

Comment: @davidb: You use [pqgrid](https://paramquery.com/), which has **no relation** with jqGrid, which use [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BackgroundColorFormatter.htm), which you referenced and the tags you used in your question. I don't know pqGrid and I can't help you with it. If you want to use jqGrid then I would recommend you [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) as the starting point.

Comment: @davidb: It seems that `render` callback function (instead of `formatter`) should be defined in case of usage `pqGrid`. See [The demo page](https://paramquery.com/demos) contains "Rows"/"Conditional formatting" (see [here](https://paramquery.com/demos/render_cells)) describes `render` more detailed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139674/discussion-between-davidb-and-oleg).

Comment: sir can you please help this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199298/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-replace-of-null-jqgrid