# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

i am new to programming. when i try this below function, it works well unless there is a blank cell in the column. if there is any blank value in the cell then it is not working and then entire page goes blank. please help me to fix.

```
        function growth (cellvalue) {
                        var gcolor;
                        var numval=cellvalue
                        var val = Number(numval.replace("%",""));
                        if (val<0) {
                            gcolor = 'red';
                        } else if (val>0) {
                            gcolor = 'green';
                        } 
                        return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' + gcolor + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
                    };
```

i have also tried this below with not equal to null like this  `if (val !== null && val<0)`

```
    function growth (cellvalue) {
var gcolor;
var numval=cellvalue
var val = Number(numval.replace("%",""));
if (val !== null && val<0) {
gcolor = 'red';
} else if (val !== null && val>0) {
gcolor = 'green';
} 
return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' + gcolor + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
};
```

both works fine when there is no blank cell. but when there is a blank cell, it is not working. please help.

## UPDATE

```
function growth (cellvalue) {
                        var numval=cellvalue
                        if(numval != null || numval != '' || numval != "")
                        {
                        var gcolor;
                        var val = Number(numval.replace("%",""));
                        if(val<0) {gcolor = 'red';}
                        else if(val >0) {gcolor = 'green';}
                        return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' + gcolor + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
                        };
                       else{return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' + white + ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';};
```

[image: browser console log]

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at HTMLTableElement.growth (lsu.php:214)
    at HTMLTableElement.R [as formatter] (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:11)
    at jquery.jqGrid.min.js:11
    at HTMLTableElement.parseDataToHtml (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:11)
    at HTMLTableElement._ (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:12)
    at D (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:12)
    at HTMLTableElement.fa (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:12)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.jqGrid.min.js:13)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)` @Asif this taken from browser log

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should test `cellvalue != null` **before** trying to parse the value. Testing for `cellvalue != null` means in JavaScript the same as `cellvalue !== null || cellvalue !== undefined`. In both cases you should don't use `cellvalue.replace` (or `numval.replace`).

The next possible problem in your code will be the usage of *numeric* values as input data. For example you can use `123` instead of `"123"`. The Number type has no method `replace` and you could have one more error. I recommend you to use `String(cellvalue)` to convert the number to the string if it's not already the string.

Try something like

```
function growth (cellvalue) {
    if (cellvalue == null) { // test for null or undefined
        return "";
    }
    cellvalue = Number(String(cellvalue).replace("%",""));
    return '<span class="cellWithoutBackground" style="background-color:' +
        (cellvalue < 0 ? 'red' : 'green') +
        ';">' + cellvalue + '</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set globally condition like

```
function growth (cellvalue) { 

if(cellvalue != null || cellvalue!= '' || cellvalue != "") {
// do stuff here
 }
 else {
  //nothing do
}
}
```

Comment: @Aisf, thank you, i have tried like this below `if(val != null || val!= '' || val != "" && val <0)` but it is not working.please advise.

Comment: did you try before the replace ? i mean check first cellvalue , if cellvalue is not null/empty then replace it.

Comment: Still you are facing problem, please debug first , value you are getting or not in browser developer tool ,OR console.log(cellvalue). . . post the value here.. let see

Comment: any solution to fix this

Comment: if is it possible for you , upload your project, somewhere else. then give me link,